# Logstash sequential thread execution flow

Tags: logstash, logstash-input-jdbc

I made two jdbc sections in my config, but I want always execute first actionA and than actionB, it's important for me. How can I do this?

Here is my config:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        type => "actionA"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mycomp:1522/db1"
        ...
        statement => "SELECT ID FROM my_table WHERE delete='Y'"
       }

    jdbc {
        type => "actionB"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mycomp:1522/db1"
        ...
        statement => "UPDATE my_table SET delete='T' WHERE delete='Y'"
       }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    if [type] == "actionA" {
        elasticsearch {
            action => "delete"
            index => "contacts"
            document_type => "contact"
            document_id => "%{id}"
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        }   
    }
    if [type] == "actionB" { }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Jay

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `schedule` parameter and make `actionA` always run before `actionB`, e.g. by making `actionA` run every even minutes (0, 2, 4, 6, ...) and `actionB` run every odd minutes (1, 3, 5, ...)

```
input {
    jdbc {
        type => "actionA"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mycomp:1522/db1"
        ...
        schedule => "*/2 * * * *" # run every even minutes
        statement => "SELECT ID FROM my_table WHERE delete='Y'"
       }

    jdbc {
        type => "actionB"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@mycomp:1522/db1"
        ...
        schedule => "1-59/2 * * * *" # run every odd minutes
        statement => "UPDATE my_table SET delete='T' WHERE delete='Y'"
       }
}
```

Comment: It's good variant and i thought about it. But if for some reason SELECT will take more time? How safe is this solution? Maybe it's possible to wait for execution of actionA?

Comment: You can always increase the delta between both actions. How often do you need them to run anyway?

Comment: I need to run it every hour. But i think it's not enterprise solution because there is no guarantee that actionB will be always done after actionA. Actually, in most situations actionA will run very fast and it's not good idea to wait e.g. 10 minutes for actionB. I think the best solution will be writing script that will wait for ending of actionA and then start actionB and start this script with help of CRONE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick for it.

Put your actions in separate files, so each file looks like this:

```
# action_X.conf
input {
    jdbc {
        # ...
    }
}
output {
    # ...
}
```

Then execute logstash manually for each file:

```
logstash -f action_a.conf
logstash -f action_b.conf
```

To repeat periodically, you could put the above commands in a shell script and add that script to the [crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/2371/708016).